# Logging all socket calls in iOS

Tags: ios, debugging, sockets, networking, cfnetwork

I am trying to trace an issue in my app and have the need to trace all calls of the BSD Socket APIs. I basically would like my function to be called whenever a socket is created, which will print logging statements containing values of key variables at the time (including the destination of the socket and port, etc.)

I want this logging to be called when my program calls socket directly (that's easy), but the hard part is I would like to have it called when socket calls are called indirectly as a result of other higher-level API calls (CFNetwork, etc.)

How can this be done?

Comment: hook `socket()` either with MobileSubstrate or by manually specifying DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES.

Comment: I want to do this on a non-jailbroken device, and I am pretty sure both solutions require one. Any other ideas?

Comment: Oh, sorry then. I think interposition requires an 'open' system.